# Locally change the scale of the chosen (mono) font without specifying its name?

Tags: fontspec, fontsize, grouping

Suppose a custom class which, thanks to package `titlesec`, prints the sections titles in uppercase. Suppose now the user of this class wants the mono font to be `Scale = MatchLowercase`. If a section title contains both main and mono fonts, the later will look too small (see MCEs below).

If the `\titleformat{\section}{...}` contains `\setmonofont[Scale = MatchUppercase]{⟨chosen mono font⟩}` the size of the mono font will be OK but, obviously, the class cannot anticipate the ⟨chosen mono font⟩ by the user, so it is a dead end. So I tried with `\defaultfontfeatures[\ttfamily]{Scale = MatchUppercase}` which doesn't needs to specify the ⟨chosen mono font⟩, but it does not have any effect.

So my question: is it possible to locally change the scale of the ⟨chosen mono font⟩ without specifying its name?

### By default or with `\defaultfontfeatures[\ttfamily]{Scale = MatchUppercase}`: doesn't look nice

```
\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{myclass.cls}
\ProvidesExplClass
  {myclass}
  {2021/06/08}
  {0.1}
  {
    My Nice Class
  }
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\LoadClass { article }
%
\RequirePackage{fontspec}
\RequirePackage{titlesec}
%
\AddToHook{begindocument/before}{%
  \titleformat{\section}{
    \normalfont
    \Large
    % \setmonofont[Scale = MatchUppercase]{RobotoMono}
    % \defaultfontfeatures[\ttfamily]{Scale = MatchUppercase}
    \bfseries
    \text_uppercase:n
  }{\thesection}{1em}{}{}
}
\end{filecontents*}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\documentclass{myclass}

\setmainfont{KpRoman}
\setsansfont{KpSans}
\setmonofont[Scale = MatchLowercase]{RobotoMono}

\begin{document}

Foo\texttt{bar}OOf

\section{Foo\texttt{bar}OOf}
\end{document}
```

[image]

### With `\setmonofont[Scale = MatchUppercase]{⟨chosen mono font⟩}`: looks nice but not realistic

```
\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{myclass.cls}
\ProvidesExplClass
  {myclass}
  {2021/06/08}
  {0.1}
  {
    My Nice Class
  }
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\LoadClass { article }
%
\RequirePackage{fontspec}
\RequirePackage{titlesec}
%
\AddToHook{begindocument/before}{%
  \titleformat{\section}{
    \normalfont
    \Large
    \setmonofont[Scale = MatchUppercase]{RobotoMono}
    % \defaultfontfeatures[\ttfamily]{Scale = MatchUppercase}
    \bfseries
    \text_uppercase:n
  }{\thesection}{1em}{}{}
}
\end{filecontents*}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\documentclass{myclass}

\setmainfont{KpRoman}
\setsansfont{KpSans}
\setmonofont[Scale = MatchLowercase]{RobotoMono}

\begin{document}

Foo\texttt{bar}OOf

\section{Foo\texttt{bar}OOf}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: well I would say the font simply doesn't fit. You are cheating with the normalsize sample as you use only lower case letters there, but as soon as you mix some uppercase into it, it looks quite awful.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is to define a new font family, perhaps

```
\newfontfamily\alttt{RobotoMono}[Scale=MatchUppercase]
\DeclareTextFontCommand\textalttt{\alttt}
```

This lets you write `\section{Foo\textalttt{bar}OOf}`.

Alternatively, you could `\addfontfeature`, as in:

```
\DeclareTextFontCommand\textrescale{\addfontfeature{Scale=MatchUppercase}}
```

You can then write `\section{Foo\texttt{\textrescale{bar}}OOf}`.

A more complex solution would be to keep the current monospace scaling in a variable, like `\ttscale`, and redefine `\ttfamily` to apply `\addfontfeature{Scale=\ttscale}`.  Consider whether it is worth this.

Comment: The first solution does the trick, but it requires an intervention of the user, which I'd like to avoid. The second one, that also requires an intervention of the user, doesn't have any effect.

Comment: @DenisBitouzé Corrected my second example so it works. How important is it that you be able to write `\texttt` instead of some other command, like `\headertt`? Seems like just as much of a user intervention either way.

Comment: Sorry, but still doesn't work (error: "Runaway argument?
`\endgroup \ttl@finmarks \@ifundefined {ttlp@section}{}{\ttlp@write {s\ETC.`
! File ended while scanning use of `\__text_expand_loop:w`."). In fact, I'd like the user to not have to use a dedicated command for content in mono font since the class will provide some "high" level commands (e.g. `\file{...}` for typesetting file names) which hide `\texttt`.

Comment: @DenisBitouzé Works for me, with a slightly-different MWE.

Comment: @DenisBitouzé Are you sure you’ll never want to do this outside a section header, and really don’t need a command for it? If so, another hack would be to declare the sections as a different language, and set a different `tt` font for that language with `\babelfont` or Polyglossia.

Comment: Could you provide your MWE that works? Also, it's rare for text to be completely in large caps, except in this case for section headings (only), so I won't need it in other contexts. Finally, the other hack would be very hacky :)

Comment: Another possibility would be to be able, at the end of the preamble, to retrieve the ⟨font name⟩ of the `tt` font passed by the user in the argument of `\setmonofont[...]{⟨font name⟩}` and thus be able to use `\setmonofont[Scale = MatchUppercase]{⟨font name⟩}` in `\titleformat{}{...}`. But I don't know if it is feasible (I'll consider ask another question).

Comment: @DenisBitouzé Yes, that is documented in section VIII.5 of the `fontspec` manual. I’m not sure how much it buys you, since your difficulty isn’t with finding the name RobotoMono.